# select maximum value for each returned record in mysql

Tags: mysql

My tables look something like this

table 1 :

```
relid  BID 
1      1
1      2
1      3
```

table 2:

```
id BID priority info 
1  1   0        Json string
2  1   1        **
3  1   2        ****
4  2   0        *** 
5  2   1        **** 

6  3   0       ****
```

the question is that I want to select all the BID's with only the highest priority from **table2** using `inner join` with **table1**, which means I want to get this result

```
id  BID  Priority info 
3   1    2        Json String info
5   2    1        *** 
6   3    0         ***
```

I've used this query and it works fine but with large numbers of records it works too slow !! the fetching time may last up to 70 seconds in **MySQL** which is a disaster for my server !!!

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.BID = table2.BID where table1.relid = 1 and table2.priority = (select max(priority) as m from table2 where table1.BID = table2.BID)
```

anyone has other suggestions that might work with better performance!

Comment: Are `relid` and `table1.id` the same thing?

Comment: yes, thanks for passing by, I've changed it

Comment: Yes, I suspect there's scope for improvement, but the first step is to select just the columns you actually want returned, instead of the evil SELECT *

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
SELECT y.id 
     , y.bid 
     , y.priority 
     , y.info
  FROM table1 x
  JOIN table2 y
    ON x.BID = y.BID 
  JOIN (SELECT bid, MAX(priority) max_priority from table2 GROUP BY bid) z
    ON z.bid = y.bid
   AND z.max_priority = y.priority
 WHERE x.relid = 1;
```

For further improvements, we'd really need to see proper CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables as well as the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: create table1 (relid int(11),bid int(11)) engine = myIsam;  create table2 (id int(11),bid int(11),proirity int(5),info Json) engine = myIsam;

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly. And MyISAM? What century is this?